# How to correctly remove interrupt callback in Beaglebone black

Tags: python, segmentation-fault, interrupt, beagleboneblack, gpio

Adding interrupt callback for gpio pin P9_24 like this

```
   class Birdemke:
        ...
        def __init__(self):
            #initializatioin of variables
            ...
            self.count = 0

        def startReadingValue(self):
            self.count = 0
            Gpio.add_event_detect("P9_24", Gpio.RISING, self.readValueFromSensor, 0)

        def pauseReadingValue(self):
            Gpio.remove_event_detect("P9_24")

        def readValueFromSensor(self):
            self.count += 1
            #reads value from i2c
            ...
```

this Birdemke class is being called from server using bottle. Calls `startReadingValue()` to add and calls `pauseReadingValue()` to make program unresponsive for rising edge. When removing event detect sometimes program is giving AttributeError at line `self.count += 1` that count variable is not defined and segmentation fault error at `Gpio.remove_event_detect("P9_24")` line [after changing adding line on top of self.count `if hasattr(self,'count')`].

Comment: is it possible you just need to initialize `self.count` in the constructor instead of `startReadingLines`?  also the `readValueFromSensor` doesn't take an instance argument so `self` would give a `NameError` before an `AttributeError` could happen

Comment: You might want to reword your post into a more specific question

Comment: hi Tadhg I changed code to correct form, actually I did typing mistake when asked this question. In my source code it was the way you said. Thanks.

Comment: hi Pseudonym I did not want to post so many lines of code here. If you advice way of solution I can try it and tell you back about result.Thanks